# Counter in Firestore database in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an Android application wherein I have to keep count of YTD, MTD, and Daily record punched for an organization as well as individual users. I tried the approach where for every save of record, I have a counter collection where I save data like

```
ORG_ORGID_2020 (for YTD)
ORG_ORGID_202005 (for MTD)
ORG_ORGID_20200513 (for Daily data)

ORG_USER1_2020 (for YTD)
ORG_USER2_202005 (for MTD)
ORG_USER3_20200513 (for Daily data)
```

so that I don't have to read many documents while fetching reports. Now to minimize the reads I save properties in the above documents (org_ID, year (i.e. 2020), yearMonth (i.e.202005), and so on. I save above documents in the form of the counter object

```
public class Counter {

@DocumentId
private String id;
private long count;
private String dealerId;
private String userId;
private String year;
private String yearMonth;
private String yearMonthDate;

}
```

Not the issue arises when I have to update the counter. I tried using

```
private FieldValue count;
```

and was able to update the count properly using

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
    counter.setCount(FieldValue.increment(1));
    counter.setDealerId(intentDealer.getId());
    counter.setYear(strFullYear);
    batch.set(dealerYtdColRef, counter, SetOptions.merge());
```

but when I try to fetch the record, I get

***java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue***

if I change the field to

```
private long count;
```

I'm not getting as, how to update the counter. I have to set all fields too along with the counter. I tried using ***.update*** method too, but it gives an error when the document is not present and has to be created for the first time.

Hw can I properly manage the counters? I'm doing counter part from app-only instead of functions because I'm trying to get the app work in free firebase tier only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the following line of code:

```
counter.setCount(FieldValue.increment(1));
```

Your `count` property is defined in your `Counter` class to be of type long. When you are using the `setCount()` method to set its value, you should pass a long value as an argument but you actually don't. The following statement:

```
FieldValue.increment(1)
```

Return an object of type [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue) and not a long, hence that error. To increment the value of your count property atomically by one, please use the following lines of code:

```
Map<String, Object> updateCount = new HashMap<>();
updateCount.put("count", FieldValue.increment(1));
yourDocRef.set(updateCount, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Alex, when I use count of type FieldValue I get an error as mentioned above java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior since `FieldValue` class is **not** Serializable. You should not change the type of your field you should leave as it is, and use the solution in my answer. Have you tried it, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, as per suggestion from Alex, I use the map values, but at the same time, I moved my code to google. Please let me know if I have done the implementation wrong. It seems to work though

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

const db = admin.firestore();
// [START_EXCLUDE]
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
db.settings(settings);
// [END_EXCLUDE]

// [START aggregate_function]
exports.aggregateEnquiries = functions.firestore
    .document('enquiries/{id}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {

        if (!change.before.exists) {
            // New document Created : add one to count

            var dealerId = change.after.data().dealerId;
            var userId = change.after.data().assignedTo;
            var date = change.after.data().createdDt.toDate();
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var yearMonth = String(year) + (month < 10 ? "0" + month : month);
            var yearMonthDate = yearMonth + (day < 10 ? "0" + day : day);

            try {
                return await db.collection("dealers").doc(dealerId)
                    .get()
                    .then((doc) => {
                        if (doc !== null && doc.exists) {
                            const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

                            db.collection("enquiries_agg")
                                .doc("D_" + dealerId + "_" + year)
                                .set({ "count": increment }, { merge: true });

                            db.collection("enquiries_agg")
                                .doc("D_" + dealerId + "_" + monthYear)
                                .set({ "count": increment }, { merge: true });

                            db.collection("enquiries_agg")
                                .doc("U_" + userId + "_" + year)
                                .set({
                                    "count": increment,
                                    "dealerId": dealerId,
                                    "userId": userId,
                                    "reference": String(year)
                                }, { merge: true });

                            db.collection("enquiries_agg")
                                .doc("U_" + userId + "_" + yearMonth)
                                .set({
                                    "count": increment,
                                    "dealerId": dealerId,
                                    "userId": userId,
                                    "reference": String(yearMonth)
                                }, { merge: true });

                            db.collection("enquiries_agg")
                                .doc("U_" + userId + "_" + yearMonthDate)
                                .set({
                                    "count": increment,
                                    "dealerId": dealerId,
                                    "userId": userId,
                                    "reference": String(yearMonthDate)
                                }, { merge: true });
                        } else {
                            console.log("error in aggregare entries.");
                        }

                        return null;
                    });
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                throw new Error("Profile doesn't exist : " + error);
            }
        } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
            // Updating existing document : Do nothing
        } else if (!change.after.exists) {
            // Deleting document : subtract one from count
        }

        return null;
    });
```